# Problems with installing .NET Maui on MacOS

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, maui, workload

When trying to install the .NET Maui workload - the installation gets stuck in this particular line every time. I have tried resetting, re-installing, and so on. The network connection is stable. Been stuck there for hours when I have tried overnight.

How do I work around this? It is the last line in the picture I posted.

[image]

Reseting, restarting and so on.

Comment: How long has it got stuck at this step? Sometimes it may take a long time to install. Is there enough.

Comment: Is your mac running out of space?